# NullReferenceException on published program but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue on any instance of this program opened from the published location or run directly from the bin folder, but not in Visual Studio, so I'm struggling to understand what's going on. The program will still run if you click continue, and as far as I'm aware loses no functionality, but the exception message is not really something I'd like people to have to click through.

Here's the code brought up by the exception:

```
public partial class CheckedList : Form
{
    public string[] list;
    public bool cancel;
    public List<string> chosen = new List<string>();

    public CheckedList(string[] _list)
    {
        list = _list;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CheckedList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (string sub in list)
            {
                if (sub.Contains("Exception 1") == false && sub.Contains("Exception 2") == false && sub.Contains("Exception 3") == false)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(sub, true);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancel = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            chosen.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And then here's the code that's bringing up the form:

```
    string[] itemSubjects = new string[i];
    i = 0;
    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in rangeAppts)
    {
        itemSubjects[i] = appt.Subject;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    CheckedList dialog = new CheckedList(itemSubjects);
    dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Exception:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Tool.CheckedList.CheckedList_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I made sure to ensure the string was filled before initializing the program, so nothing should be loaded that's null, not to mention I am ensuring that the string in CheckedList_Load is not null before doing anything with it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm not sure why this is marked as duplicate. None of my variables are null and the answer linked does not fully address this issue. The exception created seems to think a windows form that has obviously been initiated is somehow null, which would be outside the scope of the question linked.

Comment: Based on the exception, looks like `checkedListBox1` is somehow null

Comment: try to clean your project, manually delete bin folder and rebuild the solution. after that try again

Comment: This is a bit tricky but suppose that rangeAppts doesn't contains any appointement. Now you have an array of string dimensioned with i elements but every elements is by itself a null. Your check inside the load event fails because the array is not null but the elements are null. So calling Contains on a null string, kaboom...

Comment: @Damith Thanks- I've done that, however it still is not working.

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately that simply isn't the case. After hitting continue, the checkboxes are populated with strings. That would also cause an exception in VStudio during debugging which also is not happening.

Comment: @Rhumborl Yeah, I'm not sure how that's possible though.

Comment: Are you sure `i` = `rangeAppts.Count()` ? Anyway, add a check for `if (sub != null)`

Comment: @Rob Yeah, before this code I actually did a foreach, i = i+1; for a count. The rangeAppts.Count() wasn't functioning for some reason so I did that manually.
That's not what's throwing up the error, the error happens when Tool.CheckedList.CheckedList_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) is run it seems.

Comment: @Maelo I understand that line isn't throwing the error, but it's the *cause* of it, if `i` is not exactly equal to the count, you'll have an array with a null element. Changing it to `string[] itemSubjects = new string[rangeAppts.Count()];` should also fix the issue, and it's a lot clearer, too.

Comment: @Rob That's what I actually started with. For some weird reason, it always populates with hundreds of null strings instead of the actual count. It looks like using a list may fix the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create list of subjects, validate for null

```
 List<string> itemSubjects = new List<string>();
    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in rangeAppts)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appt.Subject))
        {
           itemSubjects.Add( appt.Subject);
         }
    }
    CheckedList dialog = new CheckedList(itemSubjects);
    dialog.ShowDialog();
```

change the constructor to accept the list

```
   public List<string> list;
   public CheckedList(List<string> _list)
    {
        list = _list;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

if you build application on release mode, check bin folder under release. otherwise check the bin folder inside debug.

Comment: I'm Glad that it helped you. note that null check for subject should be if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appt.Subject)

Comment: Right, I accounted for that. I went ahead and edited the missed ")" in as well on the if statement in case we have people copy/paste.
Thanks again.